# java process still living after the main function returns

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a main function that creates some child threads that does complicated stuff. I noticed that in certain scenario my main function returns but the java process is still there.  (I know the main function returns because in the last line of my main function I print a log) (I know the java process is still there because 'ps aux | grep stuff' tells me so).

I am wondering is this expected behavior? How can I make sure the java process get killed after the main function returns?

Thanks!
Erben

Comment: Could you clarify what these "certain scenarios" are?

Comment: May be your child threads are still running??
Please elaborate more / show more code

Comment: I don't have common sense in java because it is a relatively new language to me. can someone with common sense confirms that, if the main thread dies, jvm will always kills the child thread and the whole jvm process would exit?

Comment: The JVM keeps running until all *non-daemon* threads have terminated. If you're spawning more threads, the JVM will stay alive until they're finished; the main thread just becomes one more thread in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the process to end (and all child `Thread`(s)) use `System.exit(0)`.

**Example 1**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Later: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    });
    try {
        System.out.println("now: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        // System.exit(0);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("finally: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

Output is

```
now: 1413948102997
finally: 1413948102997
Later: 1413948103999
```

**Example 2**

But, remove the comment from [`System.exit(0);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) and the output is something like (no *finally* or *Later*)

```
now: 1413948221629
```

Comment: might be a noob question, is there a difference between System.exit(0) and return?

Comment: I see. even the main returns, the child thread might still get executed.

Comment: @ErbenMo Yes. [`System.exit(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) terminates the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

`main` itself is a thread. After `main` exits, the other threads are still running.

- Main exit, all exit:- To make sure you end all child threads  before `main` returns use `System.exit(0)`
- All exit, main exit:- If you want `main` thread to wait until all threads are finished use `Thread.join()`